# How to recreate deleted segments file in Lucene Index?

Tags: indexing, lucene, segment

I accidentally deleted the Lucence index folder for my program. When I run my program it shows as ...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@M:\fbl\org.fazlan.lucene.ms.demo\src\main\resources\index2 lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@cb17ecc: files: [write.lock, _0.fdt, _0.fdx]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:801)
at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.open(StandardDirectoryReader.java:52)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:66)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:291)
at org.fazlan.lucene.demo.Searcher.<init>(Searcher.java:28)
at org.fazlan.lucene.demo.FileIndexApplication.main(FileIndexApplication.java:50)
```

What can I do ? I searched through out the internet but can't find any solution ? Is there is any way to rebuilt the index with deleted segments file ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by creating an index with the same size of segments as you have now. Then using its segment file for your index. You need to replace the filenames in the segments file matching your actual file names.